# Banner Admob bloquea autoenfoque de EditText al accionar teclado Android

Tags: android, admob

Dentro de la `Activity` principal de mi app he agregado un banner de admob, el cual por alguna extraña razón impide que al seleccionar cualquier `EditText` la pantalla se autoenfoque en ese `EditText`. Si elimino el banner de mi main_activity.xml el comportamiento del teclado y los `EditText` **vuelve a la normalidad**, por lo tanto entiendo que admob es el problema. Esta es la sección de admob en mi xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/ad_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

He intantado varias soluciones pero nada funciona, por ejemplo agregué esto en mi archivo manifest en la activity de admob:

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan"
```

Lo cual tampoco ha funcionado. ¿Alguna idea para recuperar el autoajuste de los `EditText` al accionar el teclado?

**En resumen**

Esto es lo que quiero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esto es lo que estoy obteniendo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: usted dice -> ...EditText la pantalla se autoenfoque en ese EditText... y despues comenta -> ¿Alguna idea para recuperar el autoajuste del teclado?... quizas si muestra una imagen con lo que obtiene y una breve explicacion de lo que quiere sea mas facil de entender para todos (pero quizas soy yo el que no lo entiende del todo). Saludos

Comment: si tienes razon es un auto enfoque al edittext, al accionar el teclado, editaré.